# Streaming vs polling for tweets, performance?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I want to sync my database with tweets from Twitter and display them in real time, but I am not sure which one is most performant

What are the performance costs of having say, 50-100 open userstreams, compared to say, continous polling using their REST API, 50-100 times a minute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Streaming APIs are created for this purpose, the REST API isn't meant to be polled that often and will have more overhead.

Ideally you would use a sitestream instead of userstream (https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/sitestreams), but those are still in (closed) beta.